# Network streaming GStreamer C++

Tags: gstreamer, networkstream

I'm using GStreamer to take a webcam feed, edit it through OpenCV, and stream it to a network. The pipeline I'm using isn't throwing any exceptions or errors, but it also isn't streaming. I haven't the faintest idea what could be wrong.

Here's the sample of code.

```cpp
res = sprintf(pipeline2_str, "appsrc name=\"%s\" ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! queue ! udpsink port=9001", app_src_name);
```

appsrc name is coming back from OpenCV.

Comment: Now I feel dumb. It was a problem with the client!